# Understanding the meaningful of the vanishing data on the boundary of a half space. (Hormander)

Tags: operator-theory, cauchy-problem

[image]

[image]

Hi, I am reading about the concept of a characteristic Cauchy problem in Hormander's books, but not understanding the following:

**Question**. What is the meaningful of vanishing data on the boundary of the half space when this is characteristic with respect to the operator $P(D)$?